# Function from QGIS to QField on offline project file

Tags: qgis, python, qfield

Can a function created in QGIS be used in the QField program? And if it is possible, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.QField does not support user defined functions. However, it does support expressions. Are you sure an expression will not suffice?

If not, QField does support triggers, which may provide a workaround.

Comment: I use the function editor to get the expression, through which I can get the name of the device that uses the offline project. It was tested on qgis and it works normally, but when I transfer the file to qfield, the expression does not work. Is there help or a solution for that? The basis of the process is to obtain the name of the device that draws in the Qfield ( add the device name as field on layers )

Comment: What is your expression?

Comment: You could add a variable on each device, e.g. 'device_name' and then access that variable using @device_name.

Comment: Is it possible to lock the variable after adding it? So that no one can change it

Comment: My expression after added Function editor is 

get_device_name()

Comment: Please state the function definition. No, you cannot lock a variable.

Comment: I have 2 Function

Comment: import platform

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def get_device_name (feature, parent):
    return platform.node()

Comment: from qgis.core import *
import platform

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def get_device_info(feature, parent):
    os_type = platform.system()
    device_name = platform.node()
    
    if os_type == 'Windows':
        return f"Device: {device_name}, Operating System: Windows"
    elif os_type == 'Android':
        return f"Device: {device_name}, Operating System: Android"
    else:
        return f"Device: {device_name}, Operating System: Unknown"

Comment: This won't work in QField. QField does not support user defined functions. So you need a workaround. See this Issue on GitHub. https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/4635